# Parsing of Textarea with html content

Tags: html, textarea, jsoup

I work with jsoup1.6.2.jar. Consider the following code.

```
String data = "<textarea><table><tr><td>Look at the following elements</td></tr></table></textarea>"; 
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data); 
System.out.println(doc);
```

**Output:**

```
<html>  <head></head>  <body>   <textarea>&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Look at the following elements&lt;/td&lt;/tr&lt;/table</textarea>  </body> </html>
```

Why is it missing the `&gt` for self closing tags? I encountered this problem only with textarea so far. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @Quention - Indeed, deleted. Read too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a table inside a text area. There's your mistake